# Artifactory failed look for Chocolatey packages

Tags: package, artifactory, chocolatey

My Artifactory has a virtual Nuget repo which collaborated with a local Nuget repo and a remote Nuget repo which is pointing to https://chocolatey.org/api/v2.

It used to work fine when I do chocolatey package listing,
For example when I run `choco list git`, it returns:

`pygtk-all-in-one_win32_py2.7 2.24.2.2014021601
python2 2.7.15
python2-x86_32 2.7.11.20170425
tera-python27 2.7.13.20170615
vcpython27 9.0.0.30729`

But after upgrading from 6.3.0 to 6.6.1 or later, the same command can't find package anymore, the same command will return:

`vcpython27 9.0.0.30729`

This results in breaking our Chef cookbook which using `chocolatey_package` to try to install packages.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try to see if it is working when referring directly to the remote repository?